# What Windows Fonts look legible when at an angle or Slanted?

Tags: microsoft-excel, font

I often use Microsoft Excel's orientation tool to orient table header at an angle. In this way, if the header has a long text, I do not need to widen the column sizes.

[image: excel font orientation]

However, I find that the windows fonts do not look very good in the slanted position. It does not look legible, as shown below.

[image: slanted fonts]

Can someone please recommend some solution or font that may look legible?

(**Note**: Since this question was flagged as opinion-based in SuperUser. I am asking it again in the software recommendation forum.)

Comment: Q is also suitable for [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) or the [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchanges.

Comment: It's possible that the Windows rendering engine simply can't handle slanted rendering well at all. However, I'd start with checking the fonts that were specifically designed for low-resolution displays, like Tahoma, Verdana, or Georgia. I would expect that the problem you're seeing would be exacerbated by condensed fonts, so avoiding them would be recommended. It's also possible that the poor appearance may be affected by the selected point size, so try adjusting that as well.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, thank you. I tried Tahoma, Verdana and other fonts. But, you are right, the windows rendering engine itself is not designed to handle the fonts at an angle correctly.  It seems that it puts each character at an angle, you can notice it in above screenshot where 'Contact Info' has 'n', 'c', t' characters at a weird angles and are not bottom aligned. 

I suppose, I will have to live with this.